# how to traverse object value with attributes in php

Tags: php, xml

I am having my data in xml. And I want to traverse it.
When I print 
    var_dump($video_xml->playlist->video->labels->label)
the output is

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#41 (4) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(11) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["start"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["end"]=>
    string(17) "8.639527777777777"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(12) "124,66,95,45"
    ["marker"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["href"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["bold"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["italic"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["color"]=>
    string(17) "rgb(62, 201, 106)"
    ["face"]=>
    string(7) "Verdana"
    ["size"]=>
    string(2) "24"
  }
  [0]=>
  string(8) "Label1fg"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "Label0"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Label0"
}
```

however when I print each object in a foreach loop it gives

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#56 (1) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(11) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["start"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["end"]=>
    string(17) "8.639527777777777"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(12) "124,66,95,45"
    ["marker"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["href"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["bold"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["italic"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["color"]=>
    string(17) "rgb(62, 201, 106)"
    ["face"]=>
    string(7) "Verdana"
    ["size"]=>
    string(2) "24"
  }
}
```

I want to print object value like Label0.
How can I get it.
I am using following code to print label

```
foreach($video_xml->playlist->video->labels->label as $label){
        var_dump($label);
    }
```

and I am expecting output as:
string(8) "Label1fg"
string(6) "Label0"
string(6) "Label0"

Comment: where is your code? and what output you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) object behaves like an object, but is actually a system RESOURCE, (specifically a libxml resource). All its properties are also `SimpleXMLElement` objects. You need to convert each leaf node to the expected type to get primitive values (strings, f.e.).

```
foreach ($video_xml->playlist->video->labels->label as $label) {
    var_dump((string)$label);
}
```

should print what you want.

---

If the nodes of your XML document do not have attributes and you do only simple operations with it (get data from some nodes), a simpler way to work with it is to use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)/[`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert it to an multi-level array:

```
// TRUE as the second argument to json_decode() to get back arrays, not objects
$video_data = json_decode(json_encode($video_xml), TRUE));

foreach ($video_data['playlist']['video']['labels']['label'] as $label) {
    var_dump($label);
}
```

If you don't pass `TRUE` as the second argument to `json_decode()` it returns an object (`stdClass`) and you can use the existing code to navigate through it.

---

If you have to operate on the XML document structure, in my opinion it's easier to work with [`DOMElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) and the other [`DOM` classes](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).